# Error when i click on a category

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm building an e-commerce website.
I have a model with two class(Category and Product),
I recently added pagination to my list_view and its working on my products but when I click on the category class, I get an error.

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404 from .models
 import Category, Product from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required from
 django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
 from django.db.models import Q

 def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
     category = None
     categories = Category.objects.all()
     products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
     query = request.GET.get("q")
     if query:
         products = Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | 
                          Q(description__icontains=query)).distinct()
     paginator = Paginator(products, 10,)
     page = request.GET.get('page', 2)
     try:
         products= paginator.page(page)
     except PageNotAnInteger:
         # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
         products = paginator.page(1)
     except EmptyPage:
         # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
         products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
     if category_slug:
         category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug = category_slug)
         products = products.filter(category=Category)
     return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {'category':category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products, 'page': page})

 @login_required def product_detail(request, id, slug):
     product = get_object_or_404(Product,id=id,slug=slug,available=True)
     cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
     return render(request,'shop/product/detail.html', {'product': product, 'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```

When I click on product, it works fine and the pagination also works but when I click on category to display other sets of products, it displays this error:

```
 Traceback:

 File
 "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
     packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
    in inner
   35.             response = get_response(request)

 File
 "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
    packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
   in _get_response
   128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
                                                                  request)

 File
 "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
       packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
                       in _get_response
   126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, 
                                          *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\user\Documents\my webpages\socialapp\shop\views.py" in
 product_list
   30.         products = products.filter(category=Category)

 Exception Type: AttributeError at /shop/softwares-games/ Exception
 **Value: 'Page' object has no attribute 'filter'**
```

Comment: You should remove the html, css, and bootstrap-4 tags because they have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/) and your code:

- `products.filter(category=Category)`: You are trying to filter a Page object, not a manager of `Product` (because previously you are doing `products= paginator.page(page)`), thus the error.
- You should be done filtering your products before you are going to paginate them, otherwise the page numbers will never fit
- You should pass the Django page object to your template, not the page_number from the request, since that would not account for invalid values.
- Before passing the products to your template you should retrieve the matching products through `Page.object_list`

Note that i didn't test this code locally, but this should do:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        products = products.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)).distinct()
    if category_slug:
        # Re-use your category manager for the lookup
        category = get_object_or_404(categories, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=Category)
    paginator = Paginator(products, 10)
    # I would start with page 1 and name this variable page_number
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {
        'category': category, 'categories': categories, 
        'products': page.object_list, 'page': page})
```

Comment: i tried the new view but i also got this error 

File "C:\Users\user\Documents\my webpages\socialapp\shop\views.py" in product_list
  20.         products = products.objects.filter(category=Category)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /shop/clothes/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my fault (products is already a manager/queryset so no need for .objects), corrected the code. Also you should change your template to handle the `Page` object coming in instead of a single value from the request

Comment: Also i made the assumption that you want to base the queried products on available ones (thus `products.filter(Q..)` instead of `Product.objects.filter(Q..)` - if that was not your intention, switch back to that.

Comment: I removed .objects and an error showed up. 
    Int() argument must be a string,         a byte_object or a number not ModelBase. 

What do you mean by changing my template to handle the Page object and you assumption is correct. But the error showed up.

Comment: as i said i can't test it locally without having your entire project so i just write it off the top of my head - but i don't see anywhere an `int()` - are you sure that error comes from that function?

Comment: Can I get your email so I can send the github url to you.

Comment: Could you debug it on your own in the meantime?